# find a non decreasing and unbounded sequence $b_n$ s.t. $\sum \frac{1}{b_n}$ and $\sum\frac{b_n}{n^3}$ are divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find a non decreasing and unbounded sequence $b_n$ s.t. $\sum \frac{1}{b_n}$  and $\sum\frac{b_n}{n^3}$ are divergent.

My feeling is that no such sequence exist, but I must be wrong since we were asked to find such sequence.

Any sequence consisting of $n^a$ or $\log(n^a)$ did not work.

Any advice please?

Comment: In the limit $\frac{b_n}{n^3}>\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ which implies $b_n>n^{3/2}$. Thus, the sum over $b_n^{-1}$ converges

Comment: I assume the sequence should be constant most of the time with big jumps once in a while and near those jumps $b_n$ "overwhelms" $n^3$ but then is constant long enough for sum of $1/b_n$ to go to infinity. I'm not able to find such example atm.

Comment: @kingW3 Your idea is fine and can be performed as follows. It suffices to define a sequence of natural numbers so that  $(k_{n+1}-k_n)/k_n^3= 1.$ Thus $k_{n+1}= k_n^3+k_n$. Then set $b_m=k_n^3$ for $k_n\le m < k_{n+1}.$ In this way $b_{k_n}=k_n^3$ and $$\sum_{m=k_n}^{k_{n+1}-1} b_m=1$$